# Какую кодировку выбрать в Html странице для корректного отображения в IE?

Tags: html, css

В документе указана кодировка utf-8

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

в dreamweawer'е сохранил документ с кодировкой C (каноническая декомпозиция и последующая каноническая композиция) так же сохранял через обычный текстовый документ в формате utf-8. В опере, сафари и г.хроме браузерах кириллица отображается правильно - но в IE "РђРґСЂРµСЃ" вот такие чудеса происходят... не хотелось бы что бы у пользователей возникали те же проблемы... подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить? 
как заставить страницу отображаться в любом браузере в единой правильной кодировке? Или сделать чтобы страница заставляла IE отображать тексты корректно.

Вот предупреждение из IE:
HTML1114: Кодовая страница windows-1251 из (Заголовок HTTP) переопределяет конфликтующую кодовую страницу utf-8 из (Метка порядка следования байтов в кодировке Юникод)
localhost

Или это может влиять как то от настроек самого браузера?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `<meta name="charset" content="utf-8" />`

Comment: Исправил не помогло...

Comment: Какая версия ИЕ? (просто любопытно)

Comment: 11 в windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Кодовая страница windows-1251 из (Заголовок HTTP) переопределяет конфликтующую кодовую страницу utf-8 из (Метка порядка следования байтов в кодировке Юникод)

Сервер настрой, чтобы кодировка файла, кодировка, указываемая в http-заголовке, и кодировка, указываемая в meta-теге, совпадали.

Comment: Т.е. проблема в сервере? Не в коде страницы и ее кодировке? Сейчас пока страница на локальном сервере через denwer...  в любом случае сайт будет заливаться на хостинг... этих проблем там быть не должно?

Comment: @Саня, я же не знаю, в какой кодировке у тебя страница. Надо, чтобы все 3 совпадали и всё.

Comment: Все в utf-8. в целом мысль понял, Спасибо за ответ... на хост когда пойдет сайт там заморочусь уже.=)